# Why isn't bash interpreting the passed argument?

Tags: bash

I am attempting to pass an argument via getopts which is a file, ie ./file.txt or file.txt. The problem is, a function that is using the getopts arg isn't interpreting it properly, and shows as an empty arg when debugging. Code shown below:

```
 #!/bin/bash -x
checkfolders_files() {
#Check if folders exist
if [[ ! -d "${SCANS}" ]]
then
    mkdir -p ${SCANS}
elif [[ ! -d "${SCANSOUT}" ]]
then
    mkdir -p ${SCANSOUT}
fi
if [[ -f "${TARGETS}" ]]
then
    cat "${TARGETS}"
    echo "Targets file provided"
else
    cat "${TARGETS}"
    nano ${TARGETSPATH}
fi
}
SCANS='/home/test/Documents/test'
SCANSOUT="${SCANS}/${PROJ_NAME}"
TARGETSPATH="${SCANSOUT}/${PROJ_NAME}_targets.txt"
#Parse options
while getopts "n:tp" OPTION
do
    case ${OPTION} in
    n) PROJ_NAME="${OPTARG}" ;;
    t) TARGETS="${OPTARG}" ;;
    p) PROTOCOL="${OPTARG}";;
    ?) usage ;;
    esac
done
checkfolders_files
```

With the -x switch, I can see that the ${TARGETS} is actually being interpreted as empty:

```
└─$ ./test.sh -t targets.txt -n test                                                                          130 ⨯
+ SCANS=/home/test/Documents/test
+ SCANSOUT=/home/test/Documents/test/
+ TARGETSPATH=/home/test/Documents/test//_targets.txt
+ getopts n:tp OPTION
+ case ${OPTION} in
+ TARGETS=
+ getopts n:tp OPTION
+ checkfolders_files
+ [[ ! -d /home/test/Documents/test]]
+ [[ ! -d /home/test/Documents/test]]
+ [[ -f '' ]]
+ cat ''
cat: '': No such file or directory
+ nano /home/test/Documents/test//_targets.txt
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `"n:tp"` - when do you put `:` in `getopts` option string?

Comment: You forgot to declare `-t` as taking an argument, so `OPTARG` doesn't get set to `targets.txt`. (`-p` also has not been declared as taking an argument.)

Comment: @chepner Thank you! That was it! How would I maintain the p argument, but have it as optional? Ie I want it to still be an input but an optional input

Comment: `getopts` doesn't support options with optional arguments. You would have to process `$@` yourself, value by value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You failed to declare either `-t` or `-p` as taking an argument, so `OPTARG` isn't set for either option.

> getopts optstring name [args]
>
> getopts is used by shell procedures to parse positional  parameters.   optstring  contains  the  option characters to be recognized; if a character is **followed by  a  colon**,  the  option  is
> expected  to have an argument, which should be separated from it
> by white space.

A correct call to `getopts` would be

```
while getopts "n:t:p:" OPTION
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try adding a ":" after the "t" (and also after the "p") in the getopts first argument: `while getopts "n:t:p:" OPTION`

This tells `getopts` to get an argument for "-t" like it does for "-n"